# Disable/enable button depending on input text

Tags: jquery

I have this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r9rsddhk/2/) and i made the script to work when the check box is checked first and than text inserted in input,but if i try to insert text first button wont enable it self. Can someone look at that fiddle? this is my script

```
$('.checkset label').on('change', function () {
var reqlength = $('.important').length;
console.log(reqlength);
var value = $('.important').filter(function () {
    return this.value != '';
});


if ($('.checkset label').hasClass("checked")) {
    if (value.length >= 0 && (value.length !== reqlength)) {
        //alert('Please fill out all required fields.');
        $('#reg').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#reg').addClass('inactive');
    } else {
        //alert('Everything has a value.');
        $('#reg').prop('disabled', false);
        $('#reg').removeClass('inactive');
    }
} else {
    $('#reg').prop('disabled', true);
    $('#reg').addClass('inactive');
}
});
   $(".important").on('change', function () {
   $('.checkset label').change();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try substituting `input` element for `label` element at `change` events , utilizing `.toggleClass()` to set `.checked` class at on `.checkset label` if all `.important` `input` elements have, do not value

```
$(".checkset").click(function(){
  $(this).find("label").toggleClass("checked"); 
});
var res;
var inputs = $(".important, .checkset input");
inputs.on("input change", function() {
  res = inputs.get().every(function(el) {

    return $(el).is("[type=checkbox]") ? el.checked : el.value.length !== 0 
  });
    $("#reg").prop("disabled", !res)
    .toggleClass("inactive", !res)
})
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/r9rsddhk/15/

Comment: Still works the same. i need the script to make button enabled when text is inserted and checkbox is checked. for now the script works only if checkbox is checked first.

Comment: @DejanJankov Is requirement that all input elements have a value before button is enabled ?

Comment: all with class important + checkbox checked. for now i have checkbox checked + all with class important.

Comment: i don't need it to work for all input,just the input with class important

Comment: @DejanJankov Try changing selector to `var inputs = $(".important")` http://jsfiddle.net/r9rsddhk/6/

Comment: Now the button becomes enabled before the checkbox is checked.

Comment: @DejanJankov See updated post . `var inputs = $(".important", .checkset input)` http://jsfiddle.net/r9rsddhk/7/

Comment: Can you make it work with checkset label not checkbox it self? I need styled checkbox.

Comment: @DejanJankov _"Can you make it work with checkset label not checkbox it self? I need styled checkbox."_ This would not permit user to check `.checkset input` ? That is , if all `.important` have value , add `checked` class to `.checkset input` , enable button ?

Comment: look at my css in fiddle... i styled checkbox by adding background on label (.checkset label). I need my checkbox to look like that. the problem is that i don't know how ta make my script work with that style. script you wrote is good and that is what i need,but style needs to stay.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88929/discussion-between-dejan-jankov-and-guest271314).